# Display Web Service Adapter call from servlet to JSP pages

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have java servlet code like below :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

            String code = request.getParameter("code");
            String myNamespace = "wsad";
            String myNamespaceURI = "http://ws.iris.co.id/wsadev";

            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);
            SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
            /*SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();*/
            SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("getItem", myNamespace);
            SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("iDomain", myNamespace);
            SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("iCode", myNamespace);
            soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("PLS");
            soapBodyElem2.addTextNode(code);

            Source source = soapPart.getContent();


            /*Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
             transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
             transformer.transform(new DOMSource(root), new StreamResult(System.out));*/
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            String soapEndpointUrl = "http://svrqad:8080/wsadev/services/";
            String soapAction = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(soapAction), soapEndpointUrl);
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
            //String source = sourceContent.toString();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
            /*transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);*/
            /*result.setOutputStream(out);*/
            transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);

            result.setOutputStream(out);
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("GetItem.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

    }
```

It works fine when I try to run with `string [] args`. I want to display the response of the code to JSP page, anyone can help me please?
this is the output image.

[image]